# AS3: Manually calculating RGB multipliers and offsets for brightness from -1 to 1

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, colors, brightness

How would you manually calculate RGB multipliers and offsets to adjust the brightness of a color so that an argument of -1 was all black and 1 was all white?

If it's less than 1, it's easy. R, G, and B are just multiplied by (1 + brightness).

But how would you calculate the offsets for brightness values greater than 0?

Comment: For HSB/HSV it's the brightest of R,G and B ... For HSL it's the average of the darkest and brightest of R,G and B

Comment: Are you just wanting to map the usual **0 to 255** brightness range into a **-1 to 1** range? This won't introduce whitening (lightness), for that you have to map brightness into **-1 to 0** range (black level vs original color), and map lightness into **0 to 1** range (original color vs white level). Your last 2 lines are confusing... I mean couldn't that _"values greater than 0"_ be same thing as first mentioned _"If it's less than 1"_ so either way you can calculate, right? Also confusing is _"It's easy. R, G, and B are just multiplied by (1 + brightness)."_ how does this work for red =255?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simple channel per channel interpolation math. It does not look simple only because there are three channels and they need de/serialization for various purposes.

```
// Usage.

acoolor:uint = parseRGB(200, 150, 100);

trace(colorToRGB(brightNess(acoolor, 0.5)));
trace(colorToRGB(brightNess(acoolor, -0.5)));

// Implementation.

function parseRGB(ared:uint, agreen:uint, ablue:uint):uint
{
    var result:uint;

    result += (ared << 16) & 0xFF0000;
    result += (agreen << 8) & 0xFF00;
    result += (ablue) & 0xFF;

    return result;
}

function colorToRGB(acolor:uint):Array
{
    result = new Array;

    result[0] = (acolor >> 16) & 0xFF;
    result[1] = (acolor >> 8) & 0xFF;
    result[2] = (acolor) & 0xFF;

    return result;
}

function RGBToColor(anrgb:Array):uint
{
    return parseRGB.apply(this, anrgb);
}

function brightChannel(achannel:uint, adjust:Number):uint
{
    if (adjust <= -1) return 0;
    if (adjust >= 1) return 255;
    if (adjust < 0) return achannel * (1 + adjust);
    if (adjust > 0) return achannel + (255 - achannel) * adjust;

    // If adjust == 0
    return achannel;
}

function brightNess(acolor:uint, adjust:Number):uint
{
    var anrgb:Array = colorToRGB(acolor);

    for (var i:int = 0; i < 3; i++)
        anrgb[i] = brightChannel(anrgb[i], adjust);

    return RGBToColor(anrgb);
}
```